# How is ring 0 protected on Windows? Or, why do I care if Media Player gets exploited?

Tags: windows, security

I'm more familiar with the *nix environment, but I'm trying to learn about security from the Windows perspective. I see a lot of exploits and patches in the Windows security realm that seem to target peripheral programs such as Media Player or other (I would assume) user-mode programs. Is it trivial to gain root access from controlling these user programs? I would have expected exploits to target privileged programs, like `telnetd` on *nix.

Comment: Probably better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "privileged programs"?

There are two distinct things:

1. Processor execution mode (aka ring). Windows uses only two 'extreme' modes: the most privileged (ring 0) in the kernel mode and the least privileged (ring 3) in the user mode.
2. User account in the context of which the (user-mode) code runs.

The (1) may be "breached" only in case there's a bug in some driver. That is, bug in the code that by definition runs in the kernel mode, this theoretically may be exploited. Besides of this there are no vulnerabilities.

The (2) also may be breached if there're specific bugs in the driver. That is, a driver is supposed to verify the user permissions in the context of the calling process/thread, but may not always do this.

Most of the windows vulnerabilities are related to the issues in the code that runs in the user mode. Unlike unix/linux, Windows "grew up" without inherent concern to account permissions and etc. Hence when the time came to split things into free/restricted - many problems arose.

- Many windows program demand privileged account for no "good" reason, just because they do some things that "historically" were allowed in the past (such as accessing arbitrary registry settings, files in windows root directory and etc.).
- even the user-mode code that runs under a restricted account may potentially cause enough harm.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, most users on Unix systems ran programs under their "normal" user IDs. When they need root access (to perform operations that the OS deems sensitive or privileged), they su to root or run those programs under sudo. Normal applications run as the normal user which doesn't have permissions to do certain things (touch system files, open some kinds of resources, etc).

On the Windows side, users have traditionally run using accounts that have Administrator privileges (basically, root for Windows). There are a number of reasons for this but the primary one is that Windows started as a single-user operating system with no concept of users roles and, moving forward, preserving capabilities by not breaking applications has made getting users to run without Administrator privileges very hard. Current versions of Windows (Vista and Win7) default to a non-Administrator account and use the idea of [User Account Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) to let users know when something they are running requires such access, which they are required to confirm.

TL;DR - Most Windows users run with Administrator rights, so targeting normal user applications does give you privileged access in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Many media programs depend on [DirectX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectX), and other Windows libraries that are tightly integrated into the OS at a low level to minimize user-space overhead in shipping bytes around.

http://news.cnet.com/8301-1009_3-9992926-83.html

> Microsoft issued two critical security bulletin revisions on Wednesday related to vulnerabilities in Microsoft DirectX.
>   The revisions relate to holes that could allow an attacker to run code remotely on the machine or take control of it if a user opened a malicious media file.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me why user-space security would suffer if the system libraries are tightly integrated into the OS?

Comment: @RobertMartin, the TCB for user-space code typically includes large chunks of kernel-space code.  If user-space code uses a system service to open media files, and that system service can be subverted by crafted media files, then the user-space code can effectively be subverted.

Answer (score 0):

Malware running in your user context is typically somewhat easier to locate and remove than admin- or kernel-mode malware, because it can't as easily interfere with things like security software and Windows Update.  But this doesn't mean it can't achieve its purpose: it can still infiltrate your browser to interfere with, intercept or modify your web browsing, it can still send spam, it can still log keystrokes, and so on.

Comment: Could a user-level program install itself to run in the background when the system starts up?

Comment: No, but it can install itself to run in the background when the user logs in.